# CSV writer problems

Tags: python, export-to-csv

```
def little_boxes(new_frame, y_pos, box_size):
""" Arrange boxes across new frame and return a list of boolean values represting if a line is present in each box"""
    if not isinstance(new_frame, numpy.ndarray):
       raise ValueError("A valid numpy array must be passed in")
    width, height = new_frame.shape[:2]  # height, width -> y, x
    num_boxes = height / box_size[0]
    box_list = []
    for box_index in range(num_boxes):
        # Check for laser in each box
        box_x1 = box_index * box_size[1]
        box_x2 = (box_index + 1) * box_size[1]
        box_y = y_pos
        cropped_image = new_frame[box_y: box_y + box_size[1], box_x1: box_x2]
        box_list.append(laser_check(cropped_image))
    print(box_list)

    with open("output.csv","wb") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow((box_list))
    print ('output.csv')
    f.close()
```

Above is part of the code I am using to gather data from a webcam and then store the data into an excel file.  However it is only saving the last line.  For example if I get this list:

```
[1,0,0,0]

[0,1,1,1]

[0,0,1,1]
```

The only thing saved in the excel file will be `[0,0,1,1]`

Any ideas on how to fix this?  I would also like to be able to time stamp each row.

Comment: Whats `box_list`?

Comment: @Fernando I updated the question

Comment: If `laser_check` returns a plain list, then my answer is valid.

Comment: you should make sure your indentation is correct here - it's definitely not

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `box_list` is a list of lists:

```
import csv
box_list = [[1,0,0,0], [0,1,1,1], [0,0,1,1]]

with open("output.csv","wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in box_list:
        writer.writerow(row)
# no need to close f
```

Comment: or `writer.writerows(box_list)`

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to remember this one!